# phpMyAdmin TIMESTAMP выборка данных за последние 5 минут

Tags: phpmyadmin

Подскажите пожалуйста как составить запрос что бы выбрать пользователей с последней активностью в течение 5 минут. 
Пытался сделать таким запросом, но не выходит

```
SELECT id, nick, last_visit 
FROM users 
WHERE last_visit = TIMESTAMP(last_visit) - interval '5' minute 
ORDER BY last_visit DESC LIMIT 1, 30
```

Answer (score 0):

select * from users where last_visit>date_sub(now(), interval 5 minute) ;

Comment: у меня почему то не распознает функцию date_sub

Answer (score 0):

вот решение, разобрался, благодарю за отзывчивость!

SELECT id, nick, last_visit 
FROM users

```
WHERE TIMESTAMP(last_visit)>CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - interval '5' minute
```

ORDER BY last_visit 
DESC LIMIT 1, 30